# Problems with shading on curved surface

Tags: modeling, uv, shaders, lighting, matcaps

I'm having some problems with the shading on a curved surface on my model, in with the studio light with lines you can clearly see how the shading goes weird around the bend, I can't figure out how to fix it. Thanks in advance! :D

First image is the flat shaded version, second is using the built in studio MatCap, third is UV

Edit: Picture of UV added

[image: Model with wireframe]

[image: Model with studio MatCap shading]

[image]

Comment: Well If you are using UV for mapping that texture, it means your UV is not connected in those edges at all and for even worse, each island is with a different scale... Did you apply scale? How did you unwrap it? There are multiple questions, solution,s and possibilities, please clarify your situation more. show us some UV or share file with us

Comment: is it a problem of shading or a problem of UV?

Comment: I think this is one of the default builtin environment maps under the solid shading mode, created precisely for diagnosing shading and normals, since any slight discontinuity will be highly visible

Comment: I updated the pictures with description, had forgotten that... as well as added uv, the white with lines is using the build in studio MatCap. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check horizontal and check vertical matcaps are *supposed to* make objects look weird like that, in order to highlight deviation from horizontal or vertical.  Your object deviates where it should.

If you think your object looks weird try some of the default objects.  Here's a UV sphere:

[image: UV Sphere with Studiolight matcap]

Your object has good topology and reasonable UV maps.  It looks fine using, say, the metal carpaint Studiolight

[image: Object in metal carpaint mode]

Comment: Ah! Thanks, need to read up on these! Now I have one less thing to worry about!